# how to only display the graph with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm currently displaying a pie chart on my dashboard. But I would like to get rid of the title, the white backgournd (set it to transparent) the comments and everything but the pie itself.

How can I do that ? Can't find any clear how to in the official documentation.

Thanks

Comment: I've found that "To disable the title, set the text to null. Defaults to Chart title."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
             $(function () {
                $('#salesPie').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        backgroundColor:'transparent',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        default: "Chart title",
                    },
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edit my anser as per your technology:

set the background color to transparent and title to blank.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',

                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
```

Is is solve your problem?

Comment: for your kind information, you haven't mentioned about the tech.

Comment: @MilesM. I have changed my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks man, the tech was specified in the title, but not in the main content though